# Keep the values of each input in an js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

**I need to keep the values of each input in an js object.
This is my html code :**

```
<div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product One">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code One">
</div>
 <div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Two">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Two">
</div>
 <div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Three">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Three">
</div>
```

**My .js code :**

```
var variante = $('.produs_varianta');
var produs_varianta = [];
variante.each(function(index){
     produs_varianta.push(
     {
         'produs' : 'the value of product_name',
         'cod'    : 'the value of product_code
     }
   );
});
```

**
I tried using $(this).children('.product_name').val() but i've got undefined !
**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find()` as in `$(this).find(".class").val()`

```js
var variante = $('.produs_varianta');
var produs_varianta = [];
variante.each( function() {
  produs_varianta.push({
    'produs': $(this).find(".product_name").val(),
    'cod': $(this).find(".product_code").val()
  });
});

console.log(produs_varianta)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="produs_varianta">
  <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product One">
  <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code One">
</div>
<div class="produs_varianta">
  <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Two">
  <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Two">
</div>
<div class="produs_varianta">
  <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Three">
  <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Three">
</div>
```

Comment: @SoptareanuAlex If this or any other answer solved your problem, I surge that you mark one of the answers, so others can see what solve the problem you had.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a jquery function for this. Your HTML is

```
<div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product One">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code One">
</div>
 <div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Two">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Two">
</div>
 <div class="produs_varianta">
      <input type="text" class="product_name" value="Product Three">
      <input type="text" class="product_code" value="Code Three">
</div>
```

And the JQuery will be this

```
var result = [];
$('.produs_varianta').each(function( ) {
  var elem = $(this);
  var obj = {
     'product_name': elem.find('.product_name').val(),
     'product_code' : elem.find('.product_code').val()
  };
  result.push(obj);     
});

console.log(result);
```

Here is the attached link of [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kfauz7fu/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var variante = $('.produs_varianta');
    var produs_varianta = [];
    variante.each(function (index) {
        produs_varianta.push(
         {
             'produs': $(this).find('.product_name').val(),
             'cod': $(this).find('.product_code').val()
         }
       );
    });

    // NOW READ THE PRODUCTS AND ITS CODES.
    $.each(produs_varianta, function (key) {
        alert(produs_varianta[key].produs + ': ' + produs_varianta[key].cod);
    });
});
```